# How to prove R is commutative?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let R is a unitary ring, and satisfy the following relationship: $(R,+) \simeq(\mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z},+)$. Prove R is commutative.
What confuses me is the commutative property is with respect to the multiply operation in the ring, why it has a kind of relationship with the plus operation? Because of the isomorphism, I denote the elements in $R$ as follows: $0,e,a,b $. And I want to calculate some of the results under the multiplication operation. $e* 0 = 0*e=0,e*a=a*e=a,e*e = e,e*b=b*e=b$. The above four equation are all that I could calculate according to the definition. I am even confused about the result of $0*0$, because it seems it is not defined in the definition. Please help this beginner of algebra.

Comment: Hint: Can you show $b = e+a$?

Comment: "Unitary" means that $e$ in your notation is the multiplicative identity. We know the addition so $e+e=0$; then $0\cdot x=(e+e)\cdot x=x+x=0$. So the only bits of the multiplication table not yet established are $a^2,ab,ba,b^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\varphi : \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to R$ be an isomorphism between the underlying additive groups. Then we can write $R$ as $\{0_R,a,b,a+b\}$, where $a := \varphi(1,0)$ and $b := \varphi(0,1)$. Note that we only need to prove that $ab = ba$, since this implies that $a+b$ commutes with $a$ and $b$. Also note that if $a=1_R$ or $b=1_R$, then we are done; so assume that $a+b = 1_R$. It follows that: $$a^2 + ab = a(a+b) = a = (a+b)a = a^2 + ba \implies ab=ba.$$